# Why are my for loops not creating all possible combinations?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a "lock cracker" so that I'll have stuff for my resume so that I can get an internship next summer.

Each 'wheel' in the lock contains 5 letters, which are stored into charLists. I have 5 'wheels' and I'm trying to get all possible combos from the 5 wheels. In reality combo locks have 10 letters per 'wheel' but I'm trying to get the iterations working properly. However, it seems that my code only prints the same values through every iteration.

My code:

```
totalList.Add("");
for (int i = 0; i < one.Count; i++)
{

    int a = i;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < two.Count; ii++)
    {
        b = ii;
        for (int iii = 0; iii < three.Count; iii++)
        {
            c = iii;
            for (int iv = 0; iv < four.Count; iv++)
            {
                d = iv;
                for (int v = 0; v < five.Count; v++)
                {
                    e = v;
                    string myString = "" + one[a] + two[b] + three[c] + four[d] + five[e];
                    totalList.Add(myString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Visual]

Comment: doesn't seem like this is all the code

Comment: You have a really confusing way of indenting your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't really had to work with anyone else in programming so I guess I've gotten kinda sloppy.

Comment: @sweaver2112 its pretty much it. this is in a function and the 'one' two etc are the char arrays

Comment: FWIW doing a 10-level for loop is probably not going to impress many interviewers. At 5 you have to start thinking there's a better way... right?

Comment: You should show all the relavant parts of your code. Like how `one`, `two` etc are initialized etc.

Comment: I just found out that my charLists were not iterating past the first item in the string. Sorry for the waste of time guys. I really did spend hours trying to solve this. Im just not very good

Comment: BradleyDotNET - Should I implement the loops as functions? Recursively?

Comment: Recusively doesn't scale well.

Comment: Your code works fine as published. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with a single loop by considering the nature of your problem. Stepping through all possible combinations of the wheels is like counting, only in base 5 (in this case). You can count in binary and then convert each number into base 5 to translate to a wheel position set.

NOTE: If the wheels had differing number of digits, you could change to use an array of wheel sizes for pulling out each digit.

```
var allWheels = new List<char[]> { w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 };
var totalNumCombos = allWheels.Select(w => w.Length).Aggregate(1, (a, n) => a * n);

var numWheels = allWheels.Count;
var numWheelsm1 = numWheels-1;
var wheelbase = w1.Length; // use an array for different sized wheels
                           // allWheels.Select(w => w.Length).ToArray();
var allCombos = new List<string>();

var sbCombo = new StringBuilder(new String(allWheels.ToArray().Reverse().Select(w => w[0]).ToArray()));

for (int aComboInDecimal = 0; aComboInDecimal < totalNumCombos; ++aComboInDecimal) {
    var num = aComboInDecimal;
    for (var digit = 0; digit < numWheels && num > 0; ++digit) {
        var digitVal = num % wheelbase; // wheelbase[digit]
        num = num / wheelbase; // wheelbase[digit]
        sbCombo[numWheelsm1-digit] = allWheels[digit][digitVal];
    }
    allCombos.Add(sbCombo.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @Jinette - You should also upvote answers that are helpful (and definitely the one you accept)

Answer (score 0):

fyi--here's a short way to write that code including initialization.  The for loops are fine and I actually *recommend* your braces (`{}`), but the a,b,c,d,e vars are entirely superfluous (you could use the loop counters).  Same thing would work with List. 
 Anyway...shorter version:

```
        char[] w1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
        char[] w2 = { 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };
        char[] w3 = { 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o' };
        char[] w4 = { 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't' };
        char[] w5 = { 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y' };
        List<string> totalString = new List<string>();
        foreach (var c1 in w1)
            foreach (var c2 in w2)
                foreach (var c3 in w3)
                    foreach (var c4 in w4)
                        foreach (var c5 in w5)
                            totalString.Add( "" + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5);
```

Comment: When is `""+` ever useful?

Comment: When you need the correct overloaded `+`.  (I did it to remain consistent with the OP, although I don't particularly have a problem with it.)

Comment: Ah, so your `s1`, etc. should be `c1`, etc :) I think I would prefer `c1.ToString()+c2+`...

Comment: Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: This does the exact same thing that the original code does (although more efficiently). What problem does this solve?

Comment: Actually, it is possible it is less efficient - at least, using `foreach` instead of `for (int` is less efficient when iterating through a `List` so I presume the same is true for a `Array`. Enumerators have overhead.

Comment: Yeah, goal was not efficiency, but helping the OP eliminate "error surface area" by simplifying the looping code.  There were 2 indexes into each array where 0 appeared to be necessary.  It also has working hard-coded initialization in case that was the actual problem.

Comment: As a side-note, I suspect any remotely substantial efficiency gains or losses would be in the string concatenation.  A `StringBuilder` construction is something I'd certainly measure if I had 10 "wheels", or 26+ character wheels.